# I keep encountering errors saying that the dataset, tableadapters etc.. type is not defined

Tags: vb.net, forms, error-handling, windows-forms-designer, designer

I am creating a stock control program using Visual Studio 2019 and have been trying to link it to an Access database to one of the forms.

However, when I was coding my laptop crashed unexpectedly and after that errors appeared in the designer code. I know you are not supposed to edit this code so I am unsure what is causing these issues.

Also due to this my form has gone blank, yet the code for all of the buttons, textboxes etc.. still exists.

I have been researching solutions but I am just being vary of attempting any fixes as I don't want to make the problem worse.

I have included the code from the designer and screenshots of the errors.

Any help would be much appreciated as I fear that I have broken the code from regrettably clicking ignore and continue.

Thanks,

[screenshot of errors in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwFq9.png)
[screenshot of the error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGNc1.png)

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class Stock_Control
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Stock_Control
        '
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(284, 261)
        Me.Name = "Stock_Control"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub
```

## Disable Warning BC30002 ' Type 'Stock_Control.StockControlDatabaseDataSet' is not defined.

```
Friend WithEvents StockControlDatabaseDataSet As Stock_Control.StockControlDatabaseDataSet
```

## Enable Warning BC30002 ' Type 'Stock_Control.StockControlDatabaseDataSet' is not defined.

```
Friend WithEvents CustomerBindingSource As BindingSource
```

## Disable Warning BC30002 ' Type 'Stock_Control.StockControlDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.CustomerTableAdapter' is not defined.

```
Friend WithEvents CustomerTableAdapter As Stock_Control.StockControlDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.CustomerTableAdapter
```

## Enable Warning BC30002 ' Type 'Stock_Control.StockControlDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.CustomerTableAdapter' is not defined.

## Disable Warning BC30002 ' Type 'Stock_Control.StockControlDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager' is not defined.

```
Friend WithEvents TableAdapterManager As Stock_Control.StockControlDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager
```

## Enable Warning BC30002 ' Type 'Stock_Control.StockControlDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager' is not defined.

```
Friend WithEvents CustomerBindingNavigator As BindingNavigator
Friend WithEvents BindingNavigatorAddNewItem As ToolStripButton
Friend WithEvents BindingNavigatorCountItem As ToolStripLabel
Friend WithEvents BindingNavigatorDeleteItem As ToolStripButton
Friend WithEvents BindingNavigatorMoveFirstItem As ToolStripButton
Friend WithEvents BindingNavigatorMovePreviousItem As ToolStripButton
Friend WithEvents BindingNavigatorSeparator As ToolStripSeparator
Friend WithEvents BindingNavigatorPositionItem As ToolStripTextBox
Friend WithEvents BindingNavigatorSeparator1 As ToolStripSeparator
Friend WithEvents BindingNavigatorMoveNextItem As ToolStripButton
Friend WithEvents BindingNavigatorMoveLastItem As ToolStripButton
Friend WithEvents BindingNavigatorSeparator2 As ToolStripSeparator
Friend WithEvents CustomerBindingNavigatorSaveItem As ToolStripButton
```

## Disable Warning BC30002 ' Type 'Stock_Control.StockControlDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.ItemTableAdapter' is not defined.

```
Friend WithEvents ItemTableAdapter As Stock_Control.StockControlDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.ItemTableAdapter
```

## Enable Warning BC30002 ' Type 'Stock_Control.StockControlDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.ItemTableAdapter' is not defined.

```
Friend WithEvents Customer_IDTextBox As TextBox
Friend WithEvents FirstnameTextBox As TextBox
Friend WithEvents LastnameTextBox As TextBox
Friend WithEvents Street_AddressTextBox As TextBox
Friend WithEvents Town_CityTextBox As TextBox
Friend WithEvents PostcodeTextBox As TextBox
Friend WithEvents CountyTextBox As TextBox
Friend WithEvents New_CustomerCheckBox As CheckBox
Friend WithEvents ItemBindingSource As BindingSource
```

## Disable Warning BC30002 ' Type 'Stock_Control.StockControlDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.OrderTableAdapter' is not defined.

```
Friend WithEvents OrderTableAdapter As Stock_Control.StockControlDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.OrderTableAdapter
```

## Enable Warning BC30002 ' Type 'Stock_Control.StockControlDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.OrderTableAdapter' is not defined.

```
    Friend WithEvents Item_IDTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents ItemTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents BrandTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents ColourTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents SizeTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents StyleTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents PopularityTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Cost_of_ItemTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Stock_LevelTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Reorder_LevelTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Out_of_Stock_LevelTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Remaining_StockTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents OrderBindingSource As BindingSource
    Friend WithEvents Order_IDTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Item_IDTextBox1 As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Customer_IDTextBox1 As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Sale_PriceTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Delivery_ChargeTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents PromotionTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Place_of_SaleTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents ReturnedCheckBox As CheckBox
    Friend WithEvents Date_of_SaleDateTimePicker As DateTimePicker
    Friend WithEvents Date_OrderedDateTimePicker As DateTimePicker
    Friend WithEvents Quanitity_OrderedTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Cost_of_DeliveryTextBox As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents CustomerGroupBox As GroupBox
    Friend WithEvents ItemGroupBox As GroupBox
    Friend WithEvents OrderGroupBox As GroupBox
    Friend WithEvents OrderDataGridView As DataGridView
    Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1 As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn2 As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn3 As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn4 As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn5 As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn6 As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn7 As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn1 As DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn8 As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn9 As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn10 As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn11 As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Friend WithEvents CommandsGroupBox As GroupBox
    Friend WithEvents AddNewButton As Button
    Friend WithEvents Button3 As Button
    Friend WithEvents Button2 As Button
    Friend WithEvents Button4 As Button
    Friend WithEvents Button5 As Button
    Friend WithEvents KeywordTextBox As TextBox
End Class
```

Comment: have you tried restarting vs? closing the designed and code form and openagain?

Comment: @EssKay I have tried doing this and it didn't seem to make any difference unfortunately.

Comment: try comment out your code, and all of designer code.

Comment: then add back designer 25 lines at a time